# How to extract year from a DATE column and insert into new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column "date" with data type date and format "YYYY-MM-DD".

I would like to create a new column having only the year "YYYY".

I tried YEAR() and EXTRACT() functions but to my understanding those are queries and I cannot insert them into a column later on.

Any thoughts on that?(please keep in mind that I am novice at best)

Comment: I don't have a MYSQL install handy, so I can't test this, but... MYSQL has a [substring function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr).Since you know the date format, can you convert the query to a string and snip off the last six characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to update your table's schema with an `ALTER TABLE` statement as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <your_tab_name> ADD COLUMN `year` INT;
```

Then you can use an `UPDATE` statement and your function [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) to update your newly created field with the extracted year value.

```
UPDATE <your_tab_name> 
SET `year` = YEAR(`date`)
```